# Resolving undefined dependencies in C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, dependencies

Hey guys I'm really new to C++ so please be patient. I think I have a really easy problem to solve for you. I need to compile a C++ file in a virtual machine for university. 
My Input:

```
g++ decrypt_me.cpp
```

I get the following errors:

```
undefined reference to `SHA1_Init'
undefined reference to `SHA1_Update'
undefined reference to `SHA1_Final'
```

I know this has something to do with putting -lssl with it, but non of my trys worked so far.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you know that it has something to do with -lssl then why is your input not g++ -lssl decrypt_me.cpp?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)